# Сквозная аутентификация Apache

Tags: apache, active-directory, аутентификация, sssd

Хочу сделать сквозную аутентификацию используя учётную запись AD.

Имеется:

- Сервер Debian 9, присоединен к домену AD с помощью SSSD/realmd, настроен Kerberos;
- Создана сервисная учетная запись и сгенерирован keytab-файл. Добавлены SPN-записи;
- Веб-сервер: Apache2 (2.4.25-3+deb9u2);
- Icinga2 ради которой все и затеял;

Вывод keytab:

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/apache2/Apache-Krb.keytab
KVNO Timestamp Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (des-cbc-crc)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (des-cbc-md5)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (arcfour-hmac)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (des-cbc-crc)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (des-cbc-md5)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (arcfour-hmac)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
4 01.01.1970 07:00:00 HTTP/Apache-Krb.corp.domain@CORP.DOMAIN.RU (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

Строки дублируются из-за нескольких SPN-записей

Конфиг Apache:

```
Alias /icingaweb2 "/usr/share/icingaweb2/public"

AuthType Kerberos
AuthName "PAM authentication"
Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/Apache-Krb.keytab
KrbAuthRealms CORP.DOMAIN.RU
KrbMethodK5Passwd on
Require pam-account apache2-icingaweb2

Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

AllowOverride None

SetEnv ICINGAWEB_CONFIGDIR "/etc/icingaweb2"


RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /icingaweb2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex error_norewrite.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error_norewrite.html
```

Захожу на страницу 192.168.0.1/icingaweb2, или corp.domain.ru/icingaweb2 и получаю окно авторизации Apache. Дальше окна авторизации пройти не могу и получаю 401 ошибку. На сам сервер захожу под доменной учеткой admin@corp.domain.ru и никаких проблем с авторизацией нет.

Подскажите в какую сторону капать, где накосячил, что я делаю не так.